# Calling a database function to update user details

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Is there a way to use this PostgreSQL function `crypt('<password>', gen_salt('bf'))` when updating the user password using the code below?

```
def update
  @player = Player.find(params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @player.update_attributes(params[:player])
      flash[:notice] = 'Player was successfully updated.'
      format.html { redirect_to(@player) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "edit" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @player.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Why would you push an application-related concern off to your data store? Even if it is more performant per-call, your database is typically your bottleneck when you try to scale.

Comment: @coreyward: true, but the question is still interesting. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There's at least one way to use pure SQL in update - update_all method.

So to update player's password with Postgres crypt method you can do something like this:

```
Player.update_all "password = crypt('<password>', gen_salt('bf'))", "id = #{params[:id]}"
```